# proguard-android.txt was not found Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I get a warning that this file does not exist when I run the application, also in the Google Store when I upload my application produces a similar warning, I search for ways to add this file but they are old and do not work on Visual Studio 2022

I tried all the solutions for the problem, but they do not work, I did not find a way that works on Visual Studio 2022

Comment: It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201)